# Child DIV [absolute] not moving with Parent DIV in Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, accordion

I am currently test building an accordion timeline but am having issues with it in Safari & Chrome. I have a series of accordions which open and close. Each div contains a child div that should move with it when opening/closing. This works fine in Firefox but not in Chrome or Safari.

A sample is here:
http://www.evolvedublin.com/testcentre/

I'm sure its related to positioning of absolute, but maybe I have missed something? Any ideas?
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Do not post your entire website. Please provide a [reduced test case](http://css-tricks.com/reduced-test-cases/) on [dabblet](http://dabblet.com/) or [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the parent div has `position: relative` this will ensure any absolutely positioned children will be positioned relative to this parent.

In your case

```
.panel {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @trapper for your feedback. I'm afraid I had tried this - yes it does work, but the issue I then have is with the z-index and the child div. It gets hidden within the panel:
http://www.evolvedublin.com/testcentre/2/

Not sure if there is a way around this?

Comment: It's not the z-index hiding the child. It's the `overflow: hidden` on your parent. The child is bigger than the parent so the child gets clipped.

Comment: Thanks for your help @trapper, that done the trick. I just have a flicker in the child div when you open and close a panel, not to worry will look into it. Thanks.